# ploting the phase flow of a dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, graphing-functions

I have to sketch the phase flows for the following systems:

(a) $r'= (1-r^2)cosh(r)$ , $θ'=1$  ( $(r,θ)$ are polar coordinates).

(b) $x'=2xe^x$ , $y'=-y$

Considering the first equations of (a) and (b), I dont find a way to solve them explicitly (and I guess that maybe I dont have to, since the question is just "sketch the flows").

My question is, is there a programm where I can put these systems of equations and then give me the flows?

Comment: You could try: https://homepages.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/apps/slopefields.html (second and fourth tabs).

Comment: Really helpful! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wolfram Alpha and the StreamPlot function:

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7B2*x*e%5Ex%2C+-y%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-2%2C+2%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%5D](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7B2*x*e%5Ex%2C%20-y%7D%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20-2%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7By%2C%20-3%2C%203%7D%5D)

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7B%281-r%5E2%29*cosh%28r%29%2C1%2B+1e-15*theta%7D%2C+%7Br%2C+-2%2C+2%7D%2C+%7Btheta%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%5D](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=StreamPlot%5B%7B%281-r%5E2%29*cosh%28r%29%2C1%2B%201e-15*theta%7D%2C%20%7Br%2C%20-2%2C%202%7D%2C%20%7Btheta%2C%20-3%2C%203%7D%5D)

(although probably it's quite easy to sketch them by hand by linearization, see [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/linearization-near-critical-points/MIT18_03SCF11_s37_1text.pdf) for example)

Comment: Thank you very much for the links, also for the example. It is a really useful method.